# Measuring the quality of the recommender system

Tags: recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I'd like to understand how to interpret the score returned by the recommender system. 
Say, I have some interactions between an user and a book using 1-5 stars (5 is maximum). I run the evaluation for the test data set and in some cases the estimated score it let's say 5.9, more than the maximum score in the training dataset.
Should I ignore these estimations? I'm trying to find the threshold for the score to get only the best recommendations.
Thanks

Comment: If the estimates are wrong, there is probably something wrong in your calculations. Try to figure out where and why the values get calculated wrong

Answer (score 0):

You should not ignore the estimated score.  It might be an error in your model.  If all the training data scores fell between 1-5 stars, I'd wonder why your test case would result in an out of range value.